# Can we copy files from $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) to Azure Iaas server using Agent Pool “Hosted VS2017”

Tags: azure-devops, devops

We are using CI/CD pipeline in OneITVSO. Earlier we had an agent pool which was internally created. Now we are asked to use "Hosted VS 2017". We have a Database solution, ETL solution and Tabular Model solution that needs to get deployed. Additionally we have certain scope scripts.

We are able to build the solution using "Hosted VS 2017". But we are not able to deploy using "Hosted VS 2017" In the release pipeline we have a task "Windows Machine File Copy" which copies either artifacts/dacpac/ispac/.sql files from build server to dev/uat servers.

Using the earlier agent pool this pipeline was getting deployed successfully. But now when we use "Hosted VS 2017" we are getting below error:
**Failed to connect to the path \AZDEVSERVERSQL01 with the user ***domain\servicecredentialdwd*** for copying. System error 53 has occurred.**

1) Can "Hosted VS 2017" be used for task like "Windows Machine File Copy" (We are using Microsoft Azure Virtual Machine(Iaas) )

2) If we can use "Hosted VS 2017" even for Iaas Azure machines, are we missing any credential access. Should we give any access to domain\servicecredentialdwd for the agent pool "Hosted VS 2017". If so what permissions has to be given and how.

**NOTE:** *Same pipeline gets deployed when "private" agent is used. gets failed when "Hosted VS 2017" is used.*

Answer (score 1):

If your IaaS server has a public IP configured, then yes. If not, then no. The build agent has to be able to establish a network route to your virtual machine. If the VM is isolated in a private network, then the build server can't send traffic to it.

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thanks for the response. Earlier we had private agent and then this "Windows Machine File Copy" was working fine. Do you mean for private agent, we did not require such setting of public IP configuration